# CompositeControl create controls on postback?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-controls, postback

Creating a custom control 
here is the first control code

**1 . StartScreen.cs and ActDesc.cs control .**

1. The first time the page is loaded i see two edit buttons.
2. I click on any of them a see the text box with content in it.
3. Then i click the save the save button event is not fired.
4. Seems to me like controls that are created during the initial CreateChildControls fire the event. The one's that are created on Postback do not fire event.
5. I call the ControlsCreate() method on the Command event handler of the edit button . I have also tried the using the EnsureChildControls() call . Still no use ?

Can anyone guide me as to the way to achive this ?

> . .

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
namespace Cons
{
    public class StartScreen : CompositeControl
    {
        public StartScreen()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            List<Wrapper> list = new List<Wrapper>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Wrapper { Name = "D", Description = "DDDDDDDDDD" });
            }
            ActDesc desc = new ActDesc(list);
            desc.DataBind();
            this.Controls.Add(desc);
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
    }
}

public class ActDesc : CompositeControl
{
    IEnumerable<Wrapper> list = new Wrapper[] { };
    public ActDesc(IEnumerable<Wrapper> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
    private void ControlsCreate()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        Table activityDescription = new Table();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            TableRow tempRow = new TableRow();
            TableCell tempLeftCell = new TableCell();
            tempLeftCell.Text = item.Name;

            TableCell tempRightCell = new TableCell();
            tempRightCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

            if (EditId == 0)
            {
                ImageButton editButton = new ImageButton();
                editButton.ID = string.Format("editButton_{0}", i);
                editButton.ImageUrl = "add_16.png";
                editButton.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
                editButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(editButton_Command);
                editButton.CommandName = "Edit";

                tempRightCell.Controls.Add(editButton);
            }
            else
            {
                if (EditId == i)
                {
                    ImageButton saveButton = new ImageButton();
                    saveButton.ID = string.Format("saveButton_{0}", i);
                    saveButton.ImageUrl = "~/save.png";
                    saveButton.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
                    saveButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(editButton_Command);
                    saveButton.CommandName = "Save";

                    tempRightCell.Controls.Add(saveButton);
                }
            }

            tempRow.Cells.Add(tempLeftCell);
            tempRow.Cells.Add(tempRightCell);

            //Add the first row which contains the header name and the edit button if AllowEdit is true
            activityDescription.Rows.Add(tempRow);

            tempRow = new TableRow();

            tempLeftCell = new TableCell();
            tempLeftCell.ColumnSpan = 2;

            Control tempControl;
            if (EditId > 0 && EditId.Equals(i))
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                txt.ID = "txt" + i;
                txt.Text = item.Description;
                tempControl = txt;
            }
            else
            {
                Literal litContent = new Literal();
                litContent.ID = string.Format("literalContent_{0}", i);
                litContent.Mode = LiteralMode.Transform;
                litContent.Text = item.Description;

                tempControl = litContent;
            }

            tempLeftCell.Controls.Add(tempControl);
            tempRow.Cells.Add(tempLeftCell);

            // Add the second row which shows the detailed HTML description..
            activityDescription.Rows.Add(tempRow);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(activityDescription);
    }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        ControlsCreate();
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    void editButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Edit":
                string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                EditId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                ControlsCreate();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    public int EditId
    {
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["__EditId"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(this.ViewState["__EditId"]);
        }
    }
    public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a control have events, you must declare it with events.  This is in vb.net but can be converted here:  http://converter.telerik.com/ .  This also inherits from a scriptcontrol instead of a composite but it should work the same:

```
<Assembly: WebResource("myProject.FileUpload.css", "text/css", PerformSubstitution:=True)> 
< _
ToolboxData("<{0}:FileUpload ID='FileUpload{0}'  runat=""server""> </{0}:FileUpload>"), _
ClientCssResource("myProject.FileUpload.css")> _
Public Class FileUpload
    Inherits ScriptControl
    Implements INamingContainer, IPostBackEventHandler

    Private WithEvents btnMyButton As New Button

   .... 

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        'method to create my controls
        createDynamicControls()

        'if you are using update panels and wish to do an async 
        ' post back, you must first register the conrol with 
        ' the pages script manager.  If you are not using update panels, you can
        ' skip this
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Me.btnMyButton)      

        MyBase.CreateChildControls()
    End Sub

   Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
        Return New Pair(MyBase.SaveViewState(), Nothing)
    End Function


    Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
        MyBase.LoadViewState(CType(savedState, Pair).First)
        EnsureChildControls()
    End Sub

     Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        attachWebResources()
        MyBase.OnInit(e)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub

     Private Sub attachWebResources()
        'use this to attach an embedded CSS file with the DLL
        Dim styleLink As String = "<link rel='stylesheet' text='text/css' href='{0}' />"
        Dim location As String = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.[GetType](), "myProject.FileUpload.css")
        Dim styleInclude As New LiteralControl([String].Format(styleLink, location))
        DirectCast(Page.Header, HtmlControls.HtmlHead).Controls.Add(styleInclude)
    End Sub

     Protected Sub btnMyButton _click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnMyButton .Click

      '....do stuff
    end sub
        Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent
          'required for IPostBackEventHandler
    End Sub

  Private Sub createDynamicControls()
     controls.Clear()
     'instantiate your control here and add it to the controls object
  end sub
end Class
```

Let me know if this helps or if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jason . I want the events "ImageButton" click events to be fired and not any custom event for the CustomControl

Answer (score 0):

I did find an Answer to my question the problem was i think the controls to which i was not assigning an ID to where probably recreating with an different ID Hence not matching with the values saved during a previous postback . I also changed the code in the postback handler to call EnsureChildControls while setting this.ChildControlsCreated=false and thus recreating child controls.